# Table join problems in ACCESS 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I currently have two tables. Both of them have a Primary key of account_number

**purchase_email** (this_record, account_number, econtact_address)

**PURCHASE-LEDGER** (this_record, e_mail, account_number)

Currently purchase_email has all of the email address in which I wish to transfer over to the purchase-ledger table in the e_mail field which is currently empty. Below is the query which I believe is correct, however every time  I run it a window appears which is a enter parameter value for "purchase_email.econtact_address as well as another window for purchase-ledger.email. 
I am confused why it does this and have tried a number of different queries with still not failure. Can anybody help?

```
INSERT INTO [purchase-ledger] ( e_mail )
SELECT econtact_address
FROM purchase_email
WHERE purchase-ledger.account_number=purchase_email.account_number;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an UPDATE statement, not an `INSERT`:

```
UPDATE  [purchase-ledger] 
        INNER JOIN purchase_email
            ON purchase_email.Account_number = [purchase-ledger].Account_number
SET     e_mail = purchase_email.econtact_address;
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is the actual code, and not a typo, you need brackets around the table name in the WHERE clause, since there's a dash in the name.  You have:

```
INSERT INTO [purchase-ledger] ( e_mail )
SELECT econtact_address
FROM purchase_email
WHERE purchase-ledger.account_number=purchase_email.account_number;
```

You need:

```
INSERT INTO [purchase-ledger] ( e_mail )
SELECT econtact_address
FROM purchase_email
WHERE [purchase-ledger].account_number=purchase_email.account_number;
```